# SQL Joining two table

Tags: t-sql

I am struggling, maybe the simplest problem ever. My SQL knowledge pretty much limits me from achieving this. I am trying to build an sql query that should show JobTitle, Note and NoteType. Here is the thing, First job doesn't have any note but we should see it in the results. System notes never and ever should be displayed. An expected result should look like this

Result:

```
--------------------------------------------
|ID      |Title      |Note      |NoteType  |
--------------------------------------------
|1       |FirstJob   |NULL      |NULL      |
|2       |SecondJob  |CustomNot1|1         |
|2       |SecondJob  |CustomNot2|1         |
|3       |ThirdJob   |NULL      |NULL      |
--------------------------------------------
```

.

```
My query (doesn't work, doesn't display third job)

SELECT J.ID, J.Title, N.Note, N.NoteType
FROM JOB J
LEFT OUTER JOIN NOTE N ON N.JobId = J.ID
WHERE N.NoteType IS NULL OR N.NoteType = 1
```

My Tables:

```
My JOB Table
----------------------
|ID      |Title      |
----------------------   
|1       |FirstJob   |
|2       |SecondJob  |
|3       |ThirdJob   |
----------------------


My NOTE Table
--------------------------------------------
|ID      |JobId      |Note      |NoteType  |
--------------------------------------------
|1       |2          |CustomNot1|1         |
|2       |2          |CustomNot2|1         |
|3       |2          |SystemNot1|2         |
|4       |2          |SystemNot3|2         |
|5       |3          |SystemNot1|2         |
--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be true together (NoteType  can't be NULL as well as 1 at the same time):

```
     WHERE N.NoteType IS NULL AND N.NoteType = 1
```

You may want to use `OR` instead to **check if NoteType is either NULL or 1.**

```
     WHERE N.NoteType IS NULL OR N.NoteType = 1
```

**EDIT:** With corrected query, your third job will **not be retrieved as `JOB_ID` is matching but its the row getting filtered out because of the where condition.**

Try below as work around to get the third job with null values.

```
 SELECT J.ID, J.Title, N.Note, N.NoteType
 FROM JOB J
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 ( SELECT JOBID NOTE, NOTETYPE FROM NOTE 
   WHERE N.NoteType IS NULL OR N.NoteType = 1) N
 ON N.JobId = J.ID
```

Comment: Sorry I made mistake when I copied. I know It should be OR but still there is a problem.

Comment: @MehmetBudak: What is the problem? Is it same( third job not getting selected) and first job is coming?

Comment: @MehmetBudak Are you getting the first job with not and type null??

Comment: yes... my query only shows FirstJob and Second job but not third job. How can I see the third job?

Comment: @MehmetBudak: I got the answer, why are you not getting the third job. Updated the answer. Give me couple minutes to find a way out.

Comment: @MehmetBudak: Try the query in updated answer and let me know, if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

just exclude the systemNotes and use a sub-select:

```
select * from job j 
left outer join (
  select * from note where notetype!=2
) n 
on j.id=n.jobid;
```

if you include the joined table into where then left outer join might work as an inner join.

Comment: but this doesnt return the third job.